# <link rel="alternate" href="...pdf" media="print"...> not working

Tags: html, media-queries, alternate

I want an end-user to print a PDF file while printing a web page.
Stile my code does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="alternate" href="print.pdf" hreflang="en" type="application/pdf" media="print">
        <title>Pres</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know what is my mistake?
Google gives me just an info with no working example. Still referring to the 'w3.org' the "media=print" was not deprecated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

While printing a web page? Not quite sure if this is possible without some form of code like PHP. For now, just have a link that sends them to another page, where they can use the browser's built in features for printing.
In other words:

```
<a href="...pdf" target="_blank_">Download the PDF.</a>
```

This method will require them to download and then print, however this should work fine if they can print it from the browser as well.